# How to silence Rubocop warning on Assignment Branch Condition?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I would like to silence a specific Rubocop warning:

`Assignment Branch Condition size for plot_defaults is too high. [21.05/15]`

What is the appropriate syntax to do this in the code on a comment line like:

`# rubocop: disable <???>`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe this is the message for the [Metrics/AbcSize cop.](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/ca377951bb2ba17184d5ea9fb1bc8842097de1c9/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/abc_size.rb)

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
```

Comment: I would also recommend using http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/ for a quick reference

Comment: # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize not working in my case

Comment: Can you provide any additional information or the code that is not working? What version of rubocop, etc?

Comment: It works great with Rails 6.1.3.2 and Rubocop 1.15.0

Answer (score 10):

On your Rubocop config

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Enabled: false
```